# Cannot convert List<ClassA> to List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic function like this:

```
public List<T> DoStuff<T>(){
    if(typeof(T) == typeOf(ClassA))
        return CreateListWithTypeA();
    if(typeof(T) == typeOf(ClassB))
        return CreateListWithTypeB();
}
```

And the helper here:

```
public List<ClassA> CreateListWithTypeA(){
    return new List<ClassA>();
}
public List<ClassA> CreateListWithTypeB(){
    return new List<ClassA>();
}
```

Error in DoStuff():

```
Cannot convert type System.Collection.Generic.List<ClassA> to System.Collection.Generic.List<T>
```

PS: ClassA & ClassB implement an interface. Not sure if this is helpful somehow

Comment: Doesn’t really look like it makes sense to use generics in `DoStuff` if you’re just going to match a specific set of classes exactly. Why not have `DoStuffClassA` and `DoStuffClassB`?

Comment: Iam doing some refactoring and i know that i can combine CreateListWithType in the future (with a big rework of my existing project). But currently i want to bind them together to make the "frontend" more consistent. If i want to later on change the behind the scenes stuff, the api doesnt change for the whole project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a very good use of generics, as it limits `T` to be only one of two types.

But if you insist, here's how to fix your method:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>() where T : YourInterface { // The constraint here provides just a *bit* more compile time checking
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A)) {
        return CreateListWithTypeA().Cast<T>().ToList();
    }

    // other cases here...

    throw new Exception("T is not the right type!");
}
```

Comment: Upvote, yeah this will do it too. though i do think this all needs to be rethought by the op

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah, that's why I said maybe generics shouldn't be used here.

Comment: This is what i imagined. I know its not good design but its a short time compromis to make the refactoring later on easier. To give you a short idea what happened here: GetListOfType is doing some hardcoded SQL stuff, but later on i want to switch to EF.

Answer (score 3):

You could always just do this, however this is very very redundant

```
public List<T> DoStuff<T>()
{
   return new List<T>();
}
```

Assuming there is more going on in these helpers

```
public List<T> CreateListWithTypeA<T>(){
    return new List<T>();
}

...
```

if you need to access interface specific stuff use a constraints

```
where T : IMyLovelyHorse
```

If you need to new `T` up itself add `new()` constraints

```
where T : new()
```

Lastly, using  `if(typeof(T) == typeOf(ClassA))` patterns in a generic method usually point to something wrong and a need to think about things different, not always... though usually

Comment: EDIT: i cant use generics in CreateListWithType()

Comment: The easiest solution in my project would be to have a cast somehow like this: return (List<ClassA>) CreateListWithTypeA(); But it looks like something like this is not possible

Comment: @Loading Might be better to create another question, with the actual underlying problem, im sure we could solve it.

Comment: iam not sure i understand you correctly, but this is the actual problem? How to convert List<ClassA> to List<T>

Comment: @Loading `public List<T> CreateListWithTypeA<T>()` is your solve, just pass in `T` from `DoStuff<T>`